setting DISPLAY environment variable in RHEL 8 vnc switch user
in a work environment we use VNC for remote connection to RHEL-8.10 installed on a server; NICE-DCV to be specific.
For anyone's VNC session, for which everything is working with zero problems, if you do echo $DISPLAY it returns as blank.  But everything graphically works, at runlevel 5 (graphical.target).
We run various commercial software that is graphical... provides a graphical interface for users to do work with.
On occasion as an admin I have a desire to create a VNC session as root and within launch a [graphical] program as some user... so at a terminal prompt I will do su - ron, and then launch hyperworks/hypermesh for example.  This would normally be no problem graphically in the VNC session if an su did not first take place, and what happens is WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set and the program's graphical window never displays.
Is there a fix for this, what do I set the DISPLAY environment variable to (when it isn't even set to begin with) ?
I remember many years ago setenv DISPLAY 0:0 however this (or bash equivalent) does not work.

It is very strange that X11 programs are working when echo $DISPLAY returns nothing! Can you confirm that something simple like running xclock from the same terminal prompt does display a clock?

I might have been mistaken... with my root vnc session I get a :2 returned from echo $DISPLAY.  However when su'ing and doing export DISPLAY=:2 then running xclock I get Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified.  ERROR: Can't open display: :2

i probably typed DISPLAY incorrectly before when checking it with echo

xhost returns access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect and SI:localuser:root which is a specific NICE-DCV thing

OK, so now this is an X11 auth problem. In general you do not want to turn off all authentication. Before you "su" run xauth nextract /tmp/X :2  and after you "su" run xauth nmerge /tmp/X - you can use other filenames than /tmp/X of course.

hey, it works,     chmod needed on the /tmp/X file however because it was root.root  -rw-------

what's the proper way to undo this when I'm done?  Simply remove  /tmp/X or is there some command to unmerge ?

The /tmp/X file is just a way to get data between the two xauth commands, in fact the normal way would be to use a pipe but I didn't want to complicate things, although it would have saved the need for the chmod, Best way to undo it is probably to save a copy of the ~ron/.Xauthority file before the xauth nmerge, and restore it afterwards but of course that loses any other changes you have made in the mean time. If you have an environment variable called XAUTHORITY it will use that filename instead - see the man page for xauth. "unmerge" is a hard concept, prone to race conditions.
